# How to get object from a object chain

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have an object list according to a tree structure.Here is the sample code.

```
Model  model1 = [[Model alloc]init];
model1.name = @"ABC";


Model *model2 = [[Model alloc]init];
model2.name = @"DEF";


Model *model3 = [[Model alloc]init];
model3.name = @"GHI";

Model *model4 = [[Model alloc]init];
model4.name = @"JKL";

[model3.arr addObject:model4];
[model2.arr addObject:model3];
[model1.arr addObject:model2];
```

Is there any way to get  a particular object without looping each and every other object.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I didn't understand what is your requirement ?

Comment: I'm not sure what are you doing, but it's look like a perversion to set each object of an array in the next class.

Comment: yes thtz wat i'm doing

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using a array (I assume that is what `Model.arr` is) to hold the sub-models, use a dictionary as this provides fast look-up of objects without the need to trawl through the complete collection.

However in order to use a dictionary, you are going to need to supply a unique key in order to access the object.

I would also recommend **not** exposing `arr` as that means implementation changes will break dependent code; instead provide methods to add, fetch and remove sub-models:

```
- (void)addModel:(Model *)model forKey:(NSString *)key;
- (Model *)modelForKey:(NSString *)key;
- (void)removeModelWithKey:(NSString *)key;
```